# problema con vb.net y webbrowser, scraping

Tags: vb.net, scroll, navegador-web, vb

Estoy haciendo una aplicacion con vb.net con el objeto **webbrowser**.

Basicamente hago lo siguiente automaticamente, nevego a una direccion, hago scrolling hacia abajo para que cargue toda la pagina (ya que es dinamica y carga segun te desplazas hacia abajo) y por ultimo cojo los datos que quiero.

El problema es que si todo esto lo hago automatico no carga toda la pagina, pero si hago las tres acciones en el mismo orden pulsando tres botones si la carga por completo. Ignoro porque motivo al hacer el scroling el **webbrowser** se queda como bloqueado. pero si lo hago pulsando un boton no hay problema. He puesto pausas entre acciones pero no solucionan el problema

`Sytem.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000)`

edito:

```
WebOC.Navigate(link)
    Do While WebOC.ReadyState <> WebBrowserReadyState.Complete
        System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents()
    Loop

for i = 1 to 2
        webOc.Document.Window.ScrollTo(0, i*3000)
        Do While Form2.WebBrowser1.ReadyState <> WebBrowserReadyState.Complete
                System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents()
        Loop
next i
```

---- despues extraigo los datos, que si la pagina esta cargada por completo funciona

Comment: Las respuestas deben ir en el campo de respuestas abajo. No se debe editar la pregunta poniendo la solucion. Agrega la respuesta, explica porque de esa forma funciona, y 24 horas despues podes aceptar tu propia respuesta.

Comment: Loosserman, como te indica @gbianchi cada cosa en su sitio. Mira [answer] para publicar una respuesta de calidad y edita la pregunta para quitar la solución. Un saludo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Este codigo es el que me ha funcionado, no tengo claro el porque, lo que si se es que de la otra forma el navegador quedaba bloqueado y no podia cargar la pagina, vamos que se pausaba la carga del webbrowser, y de esta manera, mientras actua la pausa el webbrowser no se para.

```
Private Sub Pausa(ByVal segundos As Double)
    Dim esperaTmp As Long = My.Computer.Clock.TickCount + (segundos * 1000)
    While esperaTmp > My.Computer.Clock.TickCount
        System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents()
    End While
End Sub
```